# Using $_SESSION['token'] for forgot password management

Tags: jquery, passwords

What I am thinking ?
when user click on forgot password ---dialog box opens with email input field, where user put his email (email is checked if it exists or not by ajax)....if email exists--> submit button becomes active--->user submits--->this is also ajax submittion, where a rand() value is stored in session(token)---> this token is then sent via mail to user and sceen is shown with input field for user to give token(which is has seen from his email)----> user puts token, whiich is checked with session(token)--->if OK ----database is changed with this session(token)as new password----and then user is asked to use this token to login....

I don't know if it is correct ...but storing rand() in DB and then checking.... does not seems right because then anybody can put password change request and actual user will suffer.

oR
pls suggest some good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual workflow looks like that:

1. A user requests a password reset and enters his email address.
2. A URL with a randomly generated token as parameter is sent to the user per email. The token should not be derrived from existing values like the user id, so it cannot leak any information.
3. Only the **hash** of this token is stored in the database, thogether with the user id.
4. User clicks the link in the email.
5. Your application gets the token from the URL, calculates the hash, and searches for such a hash in the database.
6. If such a hash was found, the user can enter a new password.

It is not important whether you store the token in the database or in the session, or if the token is in a URL or must be copied, but it is important that you only store a hash of the token. The token should be strong enough (20 random characters), then it is safe to calculate a simple SHA256 without salt, which can be searched for.

The token should not be stored as new password, let the user enter his own new password when the token was valid.

Comment: Thanks for the help..just wanted to ask if session variables are destroyed when browser tab is closed or when full browser is closed.?

Comment: @user3525233 - Actually only the session cookie in the browser is destroyed, so nobody will know the session-id afterwards and the session becomes useless. From time to time the server will delete old unused sessions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a decent approach. And you shouldn't worry about the user because anybody can successfully change the password by request, only if, the user's linked email account is compromised and you can't do anything in that.
The only problem I think is that the session has that token. And if (I don't know if its possible) somehow someone extracted that token from the session then it could be disastrous.
Although a different approach would be 
To send the user a link along with the **username** and a **random key** as variables. Make a field in database to store this key in the record of the email specified. Populate this field only when request for password recovery is made.
On the page whose URL is sent, **GET the variables** from the URL and check them against the values in the database.If correct then redirect it to the page where the user himself can set the password.